# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(x-\frac{x^2}{2}) dx$?

Tags: integration

May be this is trivial but i am unable to do it. We need to find $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(x-\frac{x^2}{2}) dx$. I am getting no idea how to proceed. I think this is integrable because the leading order of $x$ is negative. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Complete the square?

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks. done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(x-\frac{x^2}{2})dx 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\big(-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-2x+1-1)\big)dx$$
$$= \exp(\frac{1}{2})\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\big(-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2\big)dx 
= (2\pi e)^\frac{1}{2}.$$